# pos_tagging and NER tagging of a MUC dataset does not work correctly

Tags: nltk, corpus, named-entity-recognition

I have a problem with MUC dataset. I want to do NER on that but all the words in this
dataset are in capital letters, so when pos_tagger is run, it detects all the words incorrectly
as a noun. To solve this problem, the whole text was turned initially to lower case. However,
this way raises another problem; if the text is in lowercase letters, the NER does not work
properly and literally finds no “PERSON, ORGANIZATION OR LOCATION”. Thus, the
conversion of the whole text to lower-case was kept, to be able to successfully pos_tag, and
then the manual capitalization of each word was performed to feed them into the NER
module. But another problem raises, this time NER detects everything as LOCATION.
Here is my code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
def NER(input_file, output_file):
    output = open('{0}_NER.txt'.format(output_file), 'w')
    testset = open(input_file).readlines()
    for line in testset:
        line_clean = line.lower().strip()
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line_clean)
        poss = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
        mylist = []
        for w in poss:
            s = list(w)
            s1 = s[0].upper()
            tmp = (s1, w[1])
            mylist.append(tmp)
        ner_ = nltk.ne_chunk(mylist)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Here is a piece of this dataset:

SAN SALVADOR, 3 JAN 90 -- [REPORT] [ARMED FORCES PRESS COMMITTEE,
COPREFA] [TEXT] THE ARCE BATTALION COMMAND HAS REPORTED THAT ABOUT 50
PEASANTS OF VARIOUS AGES HAVE BEEN KIDNAPPED BY TERRORISTS OF THE
FARABUNDO MARTI NATIONAL LIBERATION FRONT [FMLN] IN SAN MIGUEL
DEPARTMENT.  ACCORDING TO THAT GARRISON, THE MASS KIDNAPPING TOOK PLACE ON
30 DECEMBER IN SAN LUIS DE LA REINA.  THE SOURCE ADDED THAT THE TERRORISTS
FORCED THE INDIVIDUALS, WHO WERE TAKEN TO AN UNKNOWN LOCATION, OUT OF
THEIR RESIDENCES, PRESUMABLY TO INCORPORATE THEM AGAINST THEIR WILL INTO
CLANDESTINE GROUPS.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to train your own named entity classifier on case-folded text. The [nltk book](http://www.nltk.org/book/) has a step by step tutorial in chapters 6 and 7. For training you could use the [CONLL 2003 corpus](http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/ner/).

Consider also training your own POS tagger on case-folded text, it *might* work better than the nltk POS tagger you're using now (but check).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need POS tagging if your task is NER? As far as I know POS tags do not really improve the NER result. I agree with Alexis that you need to train your own classifier since you don't have access to word shape feature without case information.